# Word frequency generator in Python

Tags: python, strings

Please critique my word frequency generator. I am a beginner programmer so any criticism are welcome.

Original Code: http://pastebin.com/rSRfbnCt

Here is my revised code after the feedback:

```
import string, time, webbrowser, collections, urllib2

def timefunc(function):
    def wrapped(*args):
        start = time.time()
        data = function(*args)
        end = time.time()
        timetaken = end - start
        print "Function: "+function.__name__+"\nTime taken:",timetaken
        return data
    return wrapped

@timefunc
def process_text(text_file):
    words = text_file.read().lower().split()
    words = [word.strip(string.punctuation+string.whitespace) for word in words]
    words = [word for word in words if word]#skips ''(None) elements
    return words

@timefunc
def create_freq_dict(wordlist):
    freq_dict = collections.Counter(wordlist)
    return freq_dict

@timefunc
def create_sorted_list(freqdict):
    sorted_list = [(value,key) for key,value in list(freqdict.items())]#list() provides python 3 compatibility
    sorted_list.sort(reverse=True)
    return sorted_list

@timefunc
def write_results(sorted_list):
    text_file = open('wordfreq.txt','w')
    text_file.write('Word Frequency List\n\n')
    rank = 0
    for word in sorted_list:
        rank += 1
        write_str = "[{0}] {1:-<10}{2:->10}\n".format(rank, word[1],word[0])
        text_file.write(write_str)
    text_file.close()


## The Brothers Grimm
## This file can be obtained from Project Gutenberg:
## http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/5314/pg5314.txt
web_file = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/5314/pg5314.txt')


wordlist = process_text(web_file)
freqdict = create_freq_dict(wordlist)
sorted_list = create_sorted_list(freqdict)
results = write_results(sorted_list)

webbrowser.open('wordfreq.txt')


print "END"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import string, time, math, webbrowser

def timefunc(function, *args):
    start = time.time()
    data = function(*args)
    end = time.time()
    timetaken = end - start
```

I'd recommend calling this `time_taken` as its slightly easier to read.

```
    print "Function: "+function.__name__+"\nTime taken:",timetaken
```

Print already introduces newlines and combines different pieces. Take advantage of that.

```
   print "Function: ", function.__name__
   print "Time Taken: ", time_taken
```

That's easier to follow

```
    return data

def process_text(filename):
```

You never use filename in here, but you do use fin which is the same thing. typo?

```
    t = []
```

Not a very descriptive name. I suggest coming up with something clearer

```
    for line in fin:
        for i in line.split():
```

`i` usually means `index` which its not here

```
            word = i.lower()
            word = word.strip(string.punctuation)
            if word != '':
                t.append(word)
    return t
```

I'd do this as

```
 words = fin.read().lower().split()
 words = [word.strip() for word in words]
 words = [word for word in words if word]
 return words
```

I think its easier to follow and probably more efficient

```
def create_freq_dict(wordlist):
    d = dict()
```

`d` is not a very good name. Usually dicts are created with `{}` not `dict()`. No difference, but the first is generally preffered

```
    for word in wordlist:
        if word not in d.keys():
            d[word] = 1
        else:
            d[word] += 1
```

Use `d = collections.defaultdict(int)` or `d = collections.Counter()`. Both will make it easier to count up like this. See the python documentation for collections. You should actually be able to write this function in one line

```
    return d

def sort_dict(in_dict):
    t = []
    for key,value in in_dict.items():
        t.append((value, key))
```

`in_dict.items()` is a list already, there is no reason to copy the elements into the list. (NOTE: in Python 3.x in_dict.items() is no longer a list). Even if it wasn't a list you could do:

```
    t = list(in_dict.items())
```

Which would do the same thing your code does

```
    t.sort(reverse=True)
    return t
```

I'd implement this function as

```
return sorted(in_dict.items())
```

The sorted function takes anything sufficiently list-like and produces a sorted list from it.

```
def write_results(sorted_list):
```

sorted_list isn't a great name. It would be better to give an indication of what's in the list.

```
    fout = open('wordfreq.txt','w')
    fout.write('Word Frequency List\n\n')
    r = 0
    for i in sorted_list:
        r += 1
```

Use `for r, (key, value) in enumerate(sortedlist):` That way you don't need to manage `r` yourself, and you can refer the value as `value` rather then the harder to read `i[1]`.

```
        fillamount = 20 - (len(i[1]) + len(str(r)))
```

Some of the those parens are unnecessary.

```
        write_str = str(r)+': '+i[1]+' '+('-' * (fillamount-2))+' '+str(i[0])+'\n'
```

Multiplication has precedence, you don't need the parens to make that happen. Also, python has a method ljust which does this for you

```
        write_str = (str(r) + ': ' + i[1]).ljust('-', 20) + str(i[0]) + '\n'
```

You may also want to consider using string formatting rather then adding strings

```
 write_str = ('%d: %s' % (r, i[1])).just('-', 20) + '%d\n' % i[0]
```

I think its easier to follow, although I'd probably split across several lines

```
        fout.write(write_str)
    fout.close()


## The Brothers Grimm
## This file can be obtained from Project Gutenberg:
## http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/5314/pg5314.txt
fin = open('c:\Python27\My Programs\wx\grimm.txt')
```

fin presumable stands for file in. Give a name that indicates what's actually in it ike `grim_text`

```
wordlist = timefunc(process_text,fin)
freqdict = timefunc(create_freq_dict,wordlist)
sorted_list = timefunc(sort_dict,freqdict)
results = timefunc(write_results,sorted_list)
```

Very nice

```
webbrowser.open('wordfreq.txt')
```

That's a slightly unusual use of a webbrowser

```
print "END"
```

Comment: Thanks for the great feedback.  I have added my revised code.

Comment: @talloaktrees, nice work. Two things: 1. the `list` in `created_sorted_list` isn't necessary for Python 3 compatibility. The python 3 iterator and python 2 list are similar enough that both work in that situation. In `write_results`, use `for rank, word in enumerate(sorted_list):` then you can avoid having to keep track of rank yourself.

Comment: Yes I accidentally skipped over `enumerate(sorted_list)` when I was rewriting my code.  Also, I forgot to mention that `webbrowser.open('wordfreq.txt')` was a quick way to open up a text file in the default text editor I found somewhere.  I imagine it's a bit hackish.

Answer (score 3):

You could turn the `timefunc` function into a decorator, like this:

```
def timed(function):
    def wrapped(*args):
        start = time.time()
        data = function(*args)
        end = time.time()
        timetaken = end - start
        print "Function: "+function.__name__+"\nTime taken:",timetaken
        return data
    return wrapped
```

And then:

```
@timed
def process_text(filename):
    ...

@timed
def create_freq_dict(wordlist):
    ...
```

Etc., which would let you call your functions like this:

```
wordlist = process_text(fin)
freqdict = create_freq_dict(wordlist)
sorted_list = sort_dict(freqdict)
results = write_results(sorted_list)
```